# Why does Knex.js return max('value') as an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I want to find max value from a table:

```
knexClient
    .queryBuilder()

    .withSchema('myschema')
    .from('mytable')
    .where({some_query})
    .max('value');
```

It returns the needed value as an array with a single element:
    [{max: 1000}]

Why does it return an array, not just a number, or an object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
knexClient
    .queryBuilder()

    .withSchema('myschema')
    .from('mytable')
    .where({some_query})
    .max('value')
    .first(); // Add this to get an object
```